# CSS gradients in IE7 & IE8 is causing text to become aliased

Tags: css, text, internet-explorer, gradient

I'm attempting to use a CSS gradient in a div containing some text.  With Gecko and Webkit, the text displays fine.  In IE7 & IE8 the text appears aliased (jaggy).

I came across this blog stating: "we decided to disable ClearType on elements that use any DXTransform".

IE Blog:
http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2006/08/31/730887.aspx

That was back in 2006; 3.5 years later, I assume this bug would be fixed, but it's not.  Is there a way to do this in IE8 without resorting to stuffing a repeating background image in the div?

Here's an example of what I mean.

```
<style>
    div
    {    height:     50px; 
         background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #ddd);
         background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fff), to(#ddd));
         filter:     progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#ffffffff, endColorstr=#ffdddddd);
    }
</style>

<div>Hello World</div>
<p>Normal text</p>
```

In IE, the text in the div is aliased (jaggy), and the text in the paragraph is not.

Any solution that doesn't involve images would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not aware of any solution and it's been a known problem with IE for years as you've found out.

Answer (score 22):

There's no *good* solution to this problem.

Worse yet: `progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient` is horribly buggy so mouse events (hover, click, etc.) pass right trough it - a click on such an element *also* triggers a *seperate* click on whichever element that happens to be positions behind it. Beware!

Regardless, you better start considering which fallbacks/workarounds/NastyHacks feel acceptable to you.

Here are a few ideas off the top of my mind - in order of my personal preference:

1. Just fall-back to a plain solid `background-color` in IE and move on with your life. (Be sure to place that `background` rule *first* for it to be safely overridden/ignored by FF and Webkit.)
2. Use a `background-image` in IE. (Again place that CSS rule at *first*)
3. Keep using the gradient hack and simply 'suck it up' and accept the jaggy text for IE.
4. use Javascript (or IE's proprietary CSS `expression()` syntax) to inject an empty element, apply the gradient to it and place it behind the text.

   ```
   div {
     background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #ddd);
     background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fff), to(#ddd));
     behaviour: expression( jQuery(this).wrapInner('<div class="ie-wrap"/>').prepend('<div class="ie-gradient"/>'); this.runtimeStyle.behaviour='none'); /* disable repeat runs */
     position: relative;
   }
   div div.ie-wrap {
     position: relative;
   }
   div div.ie-gradient {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: expression( this.runtimeStyle.height=this.parentNode.clientHeight+"px" );
     filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#ffffffff, endColorstr=#ffdddddd);
   }
   ```

   (Warning: above code is untested pile of crap. and will probably *not work* as is.)
5. Keep using the gradient hack and use [Cufon](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/) to replace the jaggy text with VML rendered text. (Rests on the assumption that your site is using a typeface that allows font-embedding.)

Answer (score 3):

You could try using an IE css 3 html component, like PIE (http://css3pie.com,) which does a fairly decent job of rendering gradients. (Though this is essentially using javascript)

Comment: This is actually a failing of CSSpie :( That's what brought me here.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap the content with a DIV then add this to the DIV's css style...

```
position: relative;
```

http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_IE8_clearType_fix_when_using_filters-16676.html

Answer (score 2):

I had a situation where I wanted backgrounds of text areas to be certain colours fading horizontally to white and defined by hexadecimal in the CSS. I wanted to avoid making colour background images in case a non-developer member of my company wanted to add a new colour with hexadecimal only.

The solution I found was to make a 24-bit PNG of white gradienting into transparent set to the width of the area I was making.

I then used this IE-only hack to get the CSS to render a background colour of my choice that fades to white:

```
background /*\**/: #CCCED4 url('/white_to_transparent.png') repeat-y top left\9;
```

(the hack could be improved, but it works for me, including IE9)

Answer (score 2):

I found another inexpensive (bit opaque) solution. The text becomes anti-alised back again, when wrapping the text node and setting each element to relative position. Do not ask why...

Lets assume:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>IE8 filter problem causing jagged fonts</title>
  <style>
    html, body, div, span, b, i, ul, li, h1, h2, h3 ... to be continued {
      position: relative;
    }
    .gradient {
      filter:
        progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#ffffff', EndColorStr='#e6e6e6');
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="gradient">
    <div>I am wrapped, therefore not jagged</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope that helps anyone out there. In this case it's not necessary to use background images or derivates.

Working example in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SLZpE/2/

Answer (score 1):

This may not count as elegant (or working) solution, but how about using [Cufón](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/) for IE?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's a problem with IEx.

Try using a solid background color:

```
/*replace #ccc with the color you want*/
background: url(images/gradient-image.png) top repeat-x #ccc
```

Now, no need to use the expression *"...stuffing a repeating background image"*, since there's nothing wrong with using a background image and repeat it, we should be thankful that we can not only do that, but we can repeat it in X and Y.

Of course, you want to make your repeating background image as efficient as possible, so make it small/thin (depending on your design) and use it, rest assured, you are not doing anything wrong or against any standards or best practices.

Comment: uhm, your CSS example is a bit of a mess - but your sentiment is good.

Comment: A mess? It's just in one line, more efficient. I don't write in separate lines anymore, that method uses too much space and scrolling up and down gets tiring.

Comment: By mess I meant "completely invalid CSS syntax that will not work in any browser".